# Я подключаю телефон к компьютеру, а android studio его не видит

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Я подключил телефон к компьютеру, в режиме разработчика сделал отладку по usb и при подключении выбрал "MIDI-интерфейс", однако после этого android studio не видит мой телефон ну вообще никак. Знает ли кто-то решение этой проблемы?
У меня Ubuntu 16.04, 32 bit

Comment: А если этим же кабелем подключаешь тел просто к компу, то он его видит?  Я вообще не имею представления о `android studio`, просто я к тому, что есть кабеля которые работают только для зарядки

Comment: А почему "MIDI-интерфейс"? В режиме "MTP" должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

А вы в [51-android.rules](http:///etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.) прописывали правило для своего устройства?

В зависимости от вендора что-то типо такого:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

А потом:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Не видит студия, или не видит ADB?
Если во всплывающем окне, для выбора устройства (эмулятора или физ.устройства) у вас отсутствует физическое устройство, подключите телефон через MTP и включите в на телефоне, в режиме "Для разработчиков" отладку через usb.
Проверьте, установлен ли у вас ADB плагин для студии, да и в саму систему тоже.